# Unknown column 'i.email' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to execute my sql query but it seems something is wrong with it, can anyone correct it please.

```
SELECT * FROM (
 (SELECT i.email AS internautemail, i.compteEMVclient, i.datecreation FROM internaute i INNER JOIN lead lap ON i.id=lap.idInternaute)
   UNION
 (SELECT v.email AS usermail, v.compteEMVclient, v.datecreation FROM V2_user v INNER JOIN v2_lead vlap ON v.id=vlap.idUser)
 ) AS t
 WHERE i.compteEMVclient!=v.compteEMVclient
```

Comment: You can't give `i.email` and `v.email` different aliases in a `UNION`

Comment: `i` doesn't exist outside the subqueries, especially since you aliased the subquery results as `t`.

Comment: @AaronD actually, I am pretty sure he can; `UNION` will just ignore any aliases past those in the first query of the union.

Comment: What is the result you are trying to come up with? _...because what you have looks like an union with a condition that would be used for a JOIN._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    (
        SELECT i.email AS usermail, i.compteEMVclient, i.datecreation
        FROM internaute i
        INNER JOIN lead lap ON i.id=lap.idInternaute
        INNER JOIN V2_user v ON i.compteEMVclient!=v.compteEMVclient
        INNER JOIN v2_lead vlap ON v.id=vlap.idUser
        )
    UNION
    (
        SELECT v.email AS usermail, v.compteEMVclient, v.datecreation
        FROM V2_user v
        INNER JOIN v2_lead vlap ON v.id=vlap.idUser
        INNER JOIN internaute i ON i.compteEMVclient!=v.compteEMVclient
        INNER JOIN lead lap ON i.id=lap.idInternaute
    )
) AS t
```